# Numpy : Vector to matrix of frames

Tags: numpy, matrix, vector, linear-algebra

I want to transform a vector to a matrix of frames from the vector.
The parameters are the vector, window_size and overlap_size.
I couldn't find the operation name nor any implementation of it in numpy.

The opration I am looking for will taking the following parameters:

vector = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], window_size = 3, overlap_size=1

Will return:

output = [[1,2,3,0,0,0,0],[0,0,3,4,5,0,0],[0,0,0,0,5,6,7]]

Do you know any implementation of it in tensorflow or numpy?

Comment: Even the output of [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]] will be good